# Adding a new row in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have a sheet which contains rows with the following text (D#):

- D1
- D2
- D3

I need to add a new row "D4" (appending the next integer to the letter D) under the last entry which is "D3". Of course,next time the new entry would be "D5" etc...
How can I do that using VBA script or macro?

Comment: Record a macro doing what you want to do.  Then review what you have recorded, and clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

In the Column D enter the following Worksheet Formula and extend it to entire region:

```
="D" & ROW()
```

You can automate it via Excel VBA macro as shown in the following code snippet  which populates `Range("D1:D20")` with Worksheet Formula:

```
Range("D1:D20").Formula = "= ""D"" & Row()"
```

For your particular task, you may consider using the Macro recorder and then "polish" the VBA code.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to find the last row on your sheet:

```
ColNum = 4
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, ColNum).End(xlUp).Offset(Abs(ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, ColNum).End(xlUp).Value <> ""), 0).Row
```

The value of LastRow will be the next open row in your sheet.

To reference the cell in code use:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("D" & Trim(Str(LastRow))).Value = "YourValue"
```

or with indexes:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(LastRow, 4), Cells(LastRow, 4)).Value = "YourValue"
```

Comment: just to point out that this will work on the `ActiveSheet`, which may not always be the sheet the Op's will be working with. In this latter case, be `ws` the variable holding the worksheet object it should be used `lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, nCol).End(xlUp).Offset(Abs(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, nCol).End(xlUp).Value <> ""), 0).row`

Answer (score 0):

this fills next cell in the given column of a given worksheet with a value whose left digit part is incremented by one

```
Sub FillRow(ws As Worksheet, nCol As Long)
Dim lastRow As Long

With ws
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, nCol).End(xlUp).row
    With .Cells(lastRow, nCol)
        .Offset(1).Value = "D" & Right(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1) + 1
    End With
End With

End Sub
```